# adicionar usuario ao grupo de sudoers no Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash

Como criar um usuário e colocá-lo na lista de sudoers no linux?
Como pegar um usuário já existente e alterar o seu grupo para sudoer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu tentei encontrar aqui no SOPT e não encontrei, cheguei até a procurar no SOEN porém eu achei uma resposta mais completa no askubuntu, então vou colocar aqui o que eu fiz pra resolver, caso a pergunta esteja duplicada favor me informar pelo comentário que eu deleto se for o caso.

Para adicionar um novo usuário basta substituir o  pelo nome do seu usuário:

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

Se quiser adicionar um usuário existente ao grupo de sudo basta fazer:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>
```

O "a" é importante para que o usuário não saia dos outros grupos, já o "G" diz respeito ao grupo onde você está colocando o seu usuário.

Depois, basta sair e logar-se de novo para as mudanças surtirem efeito.

Mais referências em:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line

Comment: É que não sei se isso seria on-topic aqui, já que não é sobre programação.

Comment: Nesse caso são comandos shell script e se enquadrariam em bash e linux não?
Também fiquei na dúvida

Comment: Pelo que tenho visto no site, tem gente que acha que deve ser aceito, e gente que não acha. Vamos ver como a comunidade vai reagir a esta pergunta específica.